# IE 8 UI Issue (div goes inside another)

Tags: html, css, jsp, internet-explorer-8

[image: IE8 form image]

I am stuck with a UI issue that's replicable only on IE8 and not higher ones. The issue comes on a form where on click on submit if the top div expands (as in my case due to validation error), the bottom div (footer div) doesn't go down. Instead the top div goes under the div below it. Pls see the attached snapshot.

Also, on click or selection of the footer div using the mouse pointer, the footer div goes down as expected.

The footer div has the style as -

```
{
border-bottom: 0px
vertical-align: baseline
border-left: 0px
padding-bottom: 0px
font-style: normal
margin: 0px
font-size: 100%
vertical-align: baseline
font-weight: normal
}
```

Is there anything wrong in style elements that makes it hold its position?

I am naive as far as frontend is concerned. Any help will be appreciated on this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: please list html and the correlated css to the html. What you currently have lacks the needed information for a solution.